# External Post Request Update Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**The Problem:**

I am currently making a project that adds a device to the website by means of a post request. In theory this program should be able to get an outside post request, and then update the page that it is currently on in real time. So this webpage would receive a post request from a different language, say Python, and then in real time update/refresh the current webpage. If it makes any difference, this webpage will always be open on the target screen.

**Code:**

```
[ActionName("Index")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    AllTestsModel model = new AllTestsModel();
    List<TestConfigModel> configs = new List<TestConfigModel>();
    foreach (var item in _context.TestConfigModels)
    {
        configs.Add(item);
    }
    model.Tests = configs;
    List<Puma> pumas = new List<Puma>();
    foreach (var item in _context.Puma)
    {
        pumas.Add(item);
    }
    if (pumas.Count > 1)
    {
        pumas.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    model.ThePuma = pumas;


    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string serialNum)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(new Puma { SerialNumber = serialNum, Status = "Waiting for Tests" });
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pumas");
    }
    return View();
}
```

I have looked at several different examples, but all of them seem to be regarding internal post requests and is not what I am looking for. I've looked at ajax and javascript examples, but I'm not really sure if that is what I want/how to implement them. I am also very new to MVC/asp.net so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looking at your code you are just returning the page to the post request (So whoever sent it)  If you are looking at the server forcing and update to the UI without a request you would need some kind of 2 way communication between your frontend and controller code.  Something like SignalR or the likes. https://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: If the page you want to show has the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` setted to `*`, in modern browsers you can get it by ajax directly from JS (see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)). If no, you should get it in the server and send it to the client - you could get it in the JS from the server by ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a little bit more of research and digging, I ended up finding the answer to my question. What I ended up doing was making a little javascript function that reloads the page every five seconds to check for new updates. Since I already checked for changes to the database in my Get method for Index(), no code in my controller ended up changing.

For those who are wondering, here is the code that I ended up putting in my View for Index:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);

</script >
```